# Restore checkpoint in Tensorflow - tensor name not found

Tags: tensorflow

Trying to run the Inceptionv3 Tensorflow model with the architecture and the checkpoint provided by Google [here](https://research.googleblog.com/2016/08/improving-inception-and-image.html).

My issue is that my script crashes on `saver.restore(sess, "./inception_v3.ckpt")` with the following error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors.NotFoundError: Tensor name "InceptionV3/Mixed_5b/Branch_1/Conv2d_0b_5x5/biases" not found in checkpoint files ./inception_v3.ckpt
```

Here is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import inception_v3

with tf.Session() as sess:
  image = tf.read_file('./file.jpg')
  # code to decode, crop, convert jpeg
  eval_inputs = tf.pack([image])
  logits, _ = inception_v3.inception_v3(eval_inputs, num_classes=1001, is_training=False)
  sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

  saver = tf.train.Saver()
  saver.restore(sess, "./inception_v3.ckpt")
```

I get the same errors with the other checkpoint/model combinations so this must be an issue with my code. Not sure what I am doing wrong though.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed the checkpoint file does not contain this tensor. Can you file a bug on github?

Comment: You confirm it is an issue with the checkpoint file? What surprises me is that I get the same issue with the other checkpoint/model combinations. Surprising that they would have errors in the other model definitions too...

Comment: It looks like the checkpoint file and the code being used differ on what they expect to be there. Filing a bug will get support from the people responsible for this.

Comment: Did you file a bug on github? I can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `inception_v3()` within the `arg_scope()` returned by `inception_v3_arg_scope()` like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.contrib.slim as slim
from nets.inception_v3 import inception_v3, inception_v3_arg_scope

height = 299
width = 299
channels = 3

# Create graph
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, height, width, channels])
with slim.arg_scope(inception_v3_arg_scope()):
    logits, end_points = inception_v3(X, num_classes=1001,
                                      is_training=False)
predictions = end_points["Predictions"]
saver = tf.train.Saver()

X_test = ... # your images, shape [batch_size, 299, 299, 3]

# Execute graph
with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver.restore(sess, "./inception_v3.ckpt")
    predictions_val = predictions.eval(feed_dict={X: X_test})

predicted_classes = np.argmax(predictions_val, axis=1)
```

I recommend clearly separating the construction phase and the execution phase. Just tested on a random photo on the web, and it worked fine.  :)